# Feeling of being subjected to unfair treatment

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word, but I cannot for the life of me find it. All I can remember is the definition: the feeling of being subjected to unfair treatment (but you aren't actually, it just feels that way)

I remember watching a video on Youtube of a vet taking care of a wild animal, and the animal was very vocal and wiggling about, and the vet commented using the word that I'm trying to find; saying that it was probably feeling like "this is unfair! let me go!" even though he was just trying to help.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, but it's all I can't think about lately, so if anyone could help, thank you in advance. Even a list of possible words might be helpful as well, if that's not too much work. I will surely never forget this word after this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One appropriate adjective is **indignant**, or feeling or showing anger or annoyance at what is perceived as unfair treatment. See also the [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/indignant), e.g., ornery or cantankerous, although these capture only the general irritable behavior and not the specific cause.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much, this is definitely the word.

Answer (score 2):

**["Feeling persecuted"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecutory_delusion)** may fit the bill. The animal in your example thinks that the vet intends to cause it harm or it is worried that it will be harmed.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly 'persecutory delusion' or 'delusion of persecution'?

Was it one word or a phrase?

p.s. have you tried searching for the youtube video again?
(what animal was it, was it a particular show, etc)

Comment: I did absolutely try to search for the YouTube video again, even going through my history and searching anything I could think of, but I couldn't find it. Also my memory failed me on this one; I keep thinking it was a bird or a cat. No worries though, someone did find the word, and the definition closely matches what I was going off of in my memory. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Self-Rightous could be the word to describe that only self is feeling righteous and not just righteous alone meaning as a belief of many....I think?  Or it could also be said that the animal was feeling  "hard done by" is how I've heard that behavior described in a turn of phrase way.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be ***victimised/victimized***?